# Directional lighting in Webgl shader

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, webgl, shader, lighting

In OpenGL I could just do something like

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
...
GLfloat position[] = {-1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, color);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, position);
```

And I'd have a directional light.

How would I go about creating a directional light in a shader in webgl? In particular the following situation:

```
------------------------>     |                O
^                             ^                ^
directional light source     wall             Some object
```

Where I'd like the wall (or any other opaque objecct) to absorb out the light, preventing it from hitting object O

Comment: Do you want to implement shadows in your program?

Comment: Lighting in legacy OpenGL is little more than fancy per-vertex interpolated color based on direction / distance attenuation from a light source. What you seem to be describing implies shadow casting, which OpenGL has never supported at the API level. The pieces are in-place to implement shadows yourself, but you will have to do the dirty work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a technique called shadow mapping to get pretty nice looking shadows. Here's a tutorial I used to learn about it:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping